# How to start a new project in django using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I just installed virtualenv and in it I installed django. However, when I go to the django-admin terminal in the bin file, I wrote

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

I thought that would start a new project but it just returned

> Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).

Comment: `django-admin.py startproject mysite` the command is `django-admin.py`

Comment: **did you activate the virtualenv?** Are you sure that there is not a `mysite` folder now in your current directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is **how to start a new django project in a virtualenv**:

**1**. Create a new virtualenv for your project:

```
virtualenv py_env --python=python3
```

`--python=python3` is not mandatory. I'd recommend programming in python3.x but this is up to you. If you are unsure about what is the default python that will be used when omitting the `--python` option, type `python -V` in your terminal.

**2**. Activate the virtualenv:

```
source py_env/bin/activate
```

If you see a `(py_env)` at the beginning of the command line, then you know the virtualenv is activated. To deactivate, simply type `deactivate`.

**3**. Install the required packages:

```
pip install django
```

While this is not needed, I recommend using [ipython](http://ipython.org/), so you might want to run `pip install ipython`.

**4**. Create a new django project:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

*Hope that helped and happy coding!*

Comment: Might be better to start with pipenv these days

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first make a virtual environment:

> pip3 install --user pipenv

Make a virtual environment:

> pipenv --python 3.6

Activate the environment:

> pipenv shell

and after this do whatever you want i think it would work better now

Pipenv is best to use because it brings the best Packages of python so that there may not be further bugs while making the virtual environment. And django can be replicated properly.

Comment: OP is asking for how to use __virtualenv__, not __pipenv__.

Comment: Maybe try editing your answer to indicate any reasons why OP should instead use `pipenv`, or what are the advantages of using it.